# Removing TextDecoration from end of WPF RichTextBox run

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I have a RichTextBox with bolded text, but need to programmatically cause the bolding to "end" when the user enters a semicolon `;`.

For instance, my rich text box has the following boldedtext:

**`hello world`**

and when I add a semicolon `;`, and continue typing, I would like something along the lines of the following:

**`hello world;`**`how are you?`

I've tried something along the lines of:

```
var newRun = new Run();
paragraph.Inlines.InsertAfter(paragraph.Inlines.LastInline, newRun);
CaretPosition = newRun.ElementEnd;
```

but the newly created run seems to not be the one I'm typing into (I don't know if it just doesn't exist, or I'm just not typing into it).

Does anybody know a good way around this problem?

**Update: Works with a run with default text.**

I've noticed that if I create a run:

```
var newRun = new Run(" ")
```

then it will work, but there are cases in which I would prefer to not add a space.  Any insight?

Comment: You may be getting the position but not setting it.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.caretposition.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I set the CaretPosition variable, and didn't see anything stating that it could ignore my setting it in that link. Am I missing something?

Comment: It was only a comment.  Possibly the rtb does not have the position.  Maybe try rtb.CaretPosition = caretPos; as in the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the line :

```
CaretPosition = newRun.ElementEnd;
```

To:

```
CaretPosition = newRun.ContentEnd;
```